# How to set max zoom on map which is created using geojson-vt

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

```
     if(leafletMap == null){

    leafletMap  = L.map('mapDiv')
          .setView(defaultLocation, defaultZoom)

Layer= L.tileLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}")
   .addTo(leafletMap);

    var tileOptions = {
        maxZoom: 20,  // max zoom to preserve detail on
        tolerance: 5, // simplification tolerance (higher means simpler)
        extent: 4096, // tile extent (both width and height)
        buffer: 64,   // tile buffer on each side
        debug: 0,      // logging level (0 to disable, 1 or 2)

        indexMaxZoom: 20,        // max zoom in the initial tile index
        indexMaxPoints: 100000, // max number of points per tile in the index
    };
    //-------------------------------------------------
}

     tileIndex = geojsonvt(data, tileOptions);



    tileLayer = L.canvasTiles()
                  .params({ debug: false, padding: 5 })
                  .drawing(drawingOnCanvas)


    var pad = 0;

    tileLayer.addTo(leafletMap);
```

I did try many thing but am unable to set `max zoom` and `min zoom`. It would be good if any one will help me I have tried that but it's not working:

```
var options = {
      maxZoom: 17,
      minZoom:10
};

leafletMap  = L.map('mapDiv',undefined,options)
          .setView(defaultLocation, defaultZoom)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that this doesn't work:

```
L.map('mapDiv', undefined, options)
```

But the [Leaflet API documentation clearly states](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#map-factory) that the method signature of the `L.map()` factory is

```
L.map(id, options)
```

Makes me wonder why you put that `undefined` there in the first place.